# Ajax returning datatable always going in error part in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, ajax

I return list of values in a `datatable` and that I want to fill in `success` part of ajax function in `dropdownlist`. Till return `dt` I get all the values properly but after that it goes in `error` part. Below is what I tried.

**Ajax function**

```
function getMZONEWithState(evt) {

        var ddlState = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlState').val();

        var ddlMaintenanceZone = $("#ddlMaintenanceZone");

        ddlMaintenanceZone.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0" disabled = "disabled">State Loading...</option>');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Dashboard.aspx/GetMaintZone",
            data: JSON.stringify({ ddlState: ddlState }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {                   

            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert('Something went wrong..!!');
            }
        });
    }
```

And in code behind:-

```
[WebMethod]
    public static DataTable GetMaintZone(string ddlState)
    {   
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            CommonDB ObjCommon = new CommonDB();
            dt = ObjCommon.GetMZONE(ddlState);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {                
            throw;
        }            
    }
```

Why it always goes in `error` part I don't understand ?? Please suggest If I am going wrong anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return `DataTable` directly from your `[WebMethod]` like this. You need to convert your `DataTable` to `JSON` before sending to cleint.

Change your server side code like following.

```
        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetMaintZone(string ddlState)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                CommonDB ObjCommon = new CommonDB();
                dt = ObjCommon.GetMZONE(ddlState);
                return DataTableToJSON(dt);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        public static string DataTableToJSON(DataTable table)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> parentRow = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> childRow;
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                childRow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                {
                    childRow.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);
                }
                parentRow.Add(childRow);
            }
            return jsSerializer.Serialize(parentRow);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks PSK, it worked perfectly for me. IT will be useful for me in future also

Comment: hi PSK, can we get the same function for `Dataset` also . as in ur code u r doing it for `datatable` Please ?? its urgent

Comment: You call the same function for each table, and build you final string as output, it should be simple to implement

Comment: didn't got you.. if you dont mind please update it..it would be great